# Variable "$productSlug" is never used in operation "SingleProduct". Graphql error. Variables are not working in my Gatsby graphql queries

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am getting this error: ***Variable "$productSlug" is never used in operation "SingleProduct".***

I also use gatsby-source-wordpress to query fields from wordpress to gatsby. I also uninstalled Gatsby and re-installed it to see if it works in different versions, but it didn't.

I searched all over the internet and stack overflow for an answer,  I really believe it must be a bug with Gatsby or gatsby-source-wordpress,

this is the code:

```js
const path = require("path");
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  if (page.path.match(/products/)) {
    page.context.layout = "ArchiveProduct";
    createPage(page);
  }

  if (page.path.match(/products\/([^\/]+$)/)) {
    page.context.layout = "SingleProduct";
    createPage(page);
  }
};

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  if (node.internal.type === `allWpProduct`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` });
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    });
  }
};

exports.createPages = async function ({ graphql, actions }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query SingleProduct {
      allWpProduct {
        nodes {
          uri
          slug
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  data.allWpProduct.nodes.forEach((node) => {
    // const slug = node.slug;
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/products/" + node.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/SingleProduct.js"),
      context: {
        productSlug: node.slug,
        productId: node.id,
        layout: "SingleProduct",
      },
    });
  });
};
```

And this is the query:

```js
export const query = graphql`
  query SingleProduct($productSlug: String!) {
    wpProduct(slug: { eq: "$productSlug" }) {
      title
      slug
      link
      id
      date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
      product {
        description
        price
        slug
        photo {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query SingleProduct($productSlug: String!) {
    wpProduct(filter: {slug: { eq: "$productSlug" }}) {
      title
      slug
      link
      id
      date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
      product {
        description
        price
        slug
        photo {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Your issue appears because `$productSlug` is lifted properly via context but never used in any [sort of filtering](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/) action inside the query.

I'd recommend you check it before in the GraphiQL playground hardcoding the `$productSlug` to check the output.

Comment: it still not working, it gives me the same error: Variable "$productSlug" is never used in operation "SingleProduct"
graphql/template-strings

Comment: Have you tried it in th graphiql playground as I suggested (`localhost:8000/___graphql`)? Check the filters and the nodes available there

Comment: Yes I have tried both /_graphql and /___graphql, maybe it's Gatsby's version? Because it works in another site I used this variable built with Gatsby...